# Create dropdown list from values DB

Tags: 7, database

I got some values from the database

```
        $result = db_select('node', 'n')
        ->condition('type', 'staff_members')
        ->fields('n', array('nid', 'title'))
        ->execute();

        $options = array();

        while($row = $result->fetchAssoc()) {
            $options[] = array("nid"=>$row['nid'], "title"=>$row['title']);
        }
```

What I try to do is implement this results into my dropdown list, so I can select the node wich I need. But it's important that the title is related with the Nid, as value.

```
        $form['staff_member_options'] = array(
            '#type' => 'value',
            '#value' => array('Nid from array' => t('Title from array'))
        );
```

I don't how this is possible because I can't make a while loop in the array, I guess?

Comment: You should read the form api docmentation for Drupal 7 regarding the select element. Specifically, the #options element property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $options should be:

```
while($row = $result->fetchAssoc()) {
  $options[$row['nid']] = $row['title'];
}


$form['staff_member_options'] = array(
 '#type' => 'select',
 '#title' => t('title of the select')
 '#options' => $options
);
```